# Confusion in notation of Lusin's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

[image]

Consequence (2) of Lusin's Theorem means the supremum of the absolute value of fucntion g and f ?

The thing is that can also leads to confusion with the support definition and the bars | | could denote cardinality

Comment: In conclusion (2), we are indeed talking about the absolute values of $g$ and $f$. It would be clear if you go through the proof. Also, if you take the |.| to be mean the cardinality then, $|f(x)|=|g(x)|=1$ for all $x\in X$. Why would one even bother to write such a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it means the supremum of the absolute value.

Interpreting $|\cdot|$ as cardinality wouldn't make sense, because $g(x)$ is a number, not a set.  Also, the support of a function is usually denoted $\operatorname{supp}$ not $\sup$ to avoid this confusion.  And if they did mean the cardinality of the support, it would have to be $|\operatorname{supp} g|$, not $\operatorname{supp} |g(x)|$.  But it still wouldn't make sense in context because the supports of the functions in question will practically always be infinite sets (of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$), so the inequality would be trivial because both sides would be infinity.

Comment: right thanks. My prof. wrote sup but I copied in my notes sop and this later was defined as the support of the function which made me confused about this.